# MyEclipse not support jsf2 tags and richfaces 4 tags

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, myeclipse

I use jsf2 and richfaces4 with myeclipse 8.5
but i find it does not support those tags.
when i enter `<h:head>` and `<h:form>`
the ide show an error :

unknow resource

and i enter `a4j:`  then press "alt" + "/", there is no prompt.
how can i config the ide?

Comment: From the comments of my deleted answer this seems to be a problem of IDE configuration and not a code problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at JBoss Tools 3.2?  It supports both JSF 2 and RichFaces 4 - [JST/JSF 3.2.0.Beta2 What's New](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/jst/jst-news-3.2.0.Beta2.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are using the old jar files, which do not have those features. You should try it with new jar files.

Alternatively, the problem is you may have added two jars in lib folder or one in lib and the other is with capabilities.